# Why awk command only processes one time after I use sed command

Tags: awk, sed

The fist times, I use this command:

```
svn log -l1000 | grep '#xxxx' -B3 | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\n"; RS=""; OFS=";"} {print $1, $2}'
```

Out put are many lines. But it's not perfect as I want.
Because there are some blank lines or lines with format '----'. So, I use sed command to remove them. I use:

```
svn log -l1000 | grep '#xxxx' -B3 | sed '/^$/d' | sed '/^--/d' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\n"; RS=""; OFS=";"} {print $1, $2}'
```

I checked output of command:

```
svn log -l1000 | grep '#xxxx' -B3 | sed '/^$/d' | sed '/^--/d'
```

it looks good. But when awk process it as input text, I only see one line output.

Ah, my input likes this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
rxxxx | abc.xyz | 2016-02-01 13:42:21 +0700 (Mon, 01 Feb 2016) | 1 line

refs #kkkk [GolFeature] Fix UI 69
--
------------------------------------------------------------------------
rxxxjy | mnt.abc| 2016-02-01 11:33:45 +0700 (Mon, 01 Feb 2016) | 1 line

refs #kkkk [GoFeature] remove redundant function
--
------------------------------------------------------------------------
rxxyyxx | asdfadf.xy | 2016-02-01 11:02:06 +0700 (Mon, 01 Feb 2016) | 1 line

refs #kkkk Updated ini file
```

My expected output is:

```
2016-02-01 11:02:06 +0700 (Mon, 01 Feb 2016), rxxxx, mnt.abc, refs #kkkk Updated ini file ...
```

Comment: Stop. When you're using awk you don't need to add a dozen other commands to do pre or post processing, just stick with one awk command. Edit your question to show sample input (the output of `svn log -l1000`) and expected output for the command you need to create and we can help you.

Comment: The use of `grep -B3` is more complex to model in `awk` than normal, but adding `sed` into the mix is definitely not needed.  If `grep -B3` stays, each record (4 lines) is separated from the next by a line containing just `--` (double dash).  That should be used as the `awk` record separator, it seems to me.  Then you can print the lines you're interested in.

Comment: `#xxxx` isn't going to match the `#kkkk` in the data — please be careful and consistent.

Comment: The reason you only get one line of output is that you are setting `RS=""`, which means records are separated by one or more blank lines.  But your `sed '/^$/d'` is removing all the blank lines. So you only have one record. One record in, one record out.

Comment: @jas: thank you, I think that is exact reason.

Comment: Ed Morton, Jonathan Leffler: Thanks, I will try with FS="--"

Comment: If you posted your expected output as I suggested we could help you. Is what you posted REALLY the output of `svn log -l1000` or is it the result of you starting to process it by using `grep`? If the latter - just do what I asked.